# How to right click on a file present in a directory using AutoIT?

Tags: autoit, right-click

I am trying to simulate the functionality of automating right click of a mouse on a specific file or a folder in windows explorer and this is the code snippet I have written to simulate that :

```
#include<GUIListView.au3>

Local $filepath = "C:\Windows\addins"

Local $iPid = Run("explorer.exe /n,/e,/select," & $filepath)
ProcessWait($iPid)

Sleep(1000)

Local $hList = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:CabinetWClass]", "", "[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:1]")

Local $aClient = WinGetPos($hList)
Local $aPos = _GUICtrlListView_GetItemPosition($hList, _GUICtrlListView_GetSelectedIndices($hList))

MouseClick("Right", $aClient[0] + $aPos[0] + 4, $aClient[1] + $aPos[1] + 4)
```

but this returns me an error saying this :

> > "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut "C:\Users\asablok\Desktop\My Documents\Calculator.au3"
> >     "C:\Users\asablok\Desktop\My Documents\Calculator.au3" (15) : ==>
> >     Subscript used on non-accessible variable.: MouseClick("Right",
> >     $aClient[0] + $aPos[0] + 4, $aClient[1] + $aPos[1] + 4)
> >     MouseClick("Right", $aClient^ ERROR
> >     Exit code: 1    Time: 1.593

Can anyone suggest me a workaround as to how to address this problem of simulating right clicking using AutoIT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include<GUIListView.au3>

Local $filepath = "C:\Windows\addins"

Local $iPid = Run("explorer.exe /n,/e,/select," & $filepath)
ProcessWait($iPid)

Sleep(1000)

Send('+{F10}')
```

Comment: It seems to work!! Thanks a lot :D I was able to achieve what I wanted, now I have one other problem related to this, how do I select a specific option from the menu that appears after the right click, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: BlockInput(1)
Send("{down 8}")
Send("{ENTER}")
BlockInput(0)

I suggest using BlockInput whenever you want to protect from interfering with the script while using Send()

Comment: Hi Milos thanks for replying man, let me explain my situation, the thing I want to do is, first I should be able to open the desired directory lets say "C:/" and in that directory I need to right click on the specific folder and get the list of options from the menu that appears, like if the menu has Open, OpenWith and Properties I need to get all these options in an array.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:

These are the function you need.
Fiddle with them and you will figure it out.

```
#include-once
#include <GuiMenu.au3>
;#include <GuiToolbar.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
Opt("MustDeclareVars", 1)

Global $gaPopups[1][3] = [[0, 0]]

Func _Lib_PopupGetHwnd($iIndex = 1)
    _Lib_PopupWait()
    Return $gaPopups[$iIndex][0]
EndFunc   ;==>_Lib_PopupGetHwnd

Func _Lib_PopupScan()
    Local $iI, $sClass, $hWnd, $hMenu
    ReDim $gaPopups[1][3]
    $gaPopups[0][0] = 0
    ReDim $winapi_gaWinList[64][2]
    $winapi_gaWinList[0][0] = 0
    $winapi_gaWinList[0][1] = 64
    _WinAPI_EnumWindowsPopup()
    For $iI = 1 To $winapi_gaWinList[0][0]
        $hWnd = $winapi_gaWinList[$iI][0]
        $sClass = $winapi_gaWinList[$iI][1]
        Select
            Case $sClass = "#32768"
                $hMenu = _SendMessage($hWnd, $MN_GETHMENU, 0, 0)
                _Lib_PopupAdd($hMenu, 1, $hWnd)
            Case $sClass = "ToolbarWindow32"
                _Lib_PopupAdd($hWnd, 2, _WinAPI_GetParent($hWnd))
            Case $sClass = "ToolTips_Class32"
                _Lib_PopupAdd($hWnd, 3, _WinAPI_GetParent($hWnd))
        EndSelect
    Next
EndFunc   ;==>_Lib_PopupScan

Func _Lib_PopupWait()
    Local $iLoop = 0
    While $iLoop < 50
        If $gaPopups[0][0] > 0 Then Return
        Sleep(100)
        _Lib_PopupScan()
        $iLoop += 1
    WEnd
    ConsoleWrite("Timeout waiting for popup window to appear" & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>_Lib_PopupWait

Func _Lib_PopupAdd($hWnd, $iType, $hParent)
    Local $iCount
    $gaPopups[0][0] += 1
    $iCount = $gaPopups[0][0]
    ReDim $gaPopups[$iCount + 1][3]
    $gaPopups[$iCount][0] = $hWnd
    $gaPopups[$iCount][1] = $iType
    $gaPopups[$iCount][2] = $hParent
EndFunc   ;==>_Lib_PopupAdd
```

Comment: Yeah I found this example, but I am not able to modify this to select only just a desired option :(

Comment: I want to get the contents of the context Menu and the above code uses a constants file which might vary depending upon the version of Windows I am using, isn't there a way to get the handle of the context menu window and get the list of menu items in an array or a list using AutoIt, I researched on the AutoIT forums but very less help is available there :( sadly

Comment: That is what is required of me, the thing is I am trying to automate a plugin, what happens is I first open the required folder, then right click on a specific file and then from the list of menus available in the pop-up I need to select the one I need to click so for this I need a list of all the menu items available in the pop-up and then I hit the left-click to carry out the process, is there someway it can be done using AutoIT. I have searched a lot but unlucky :(

Comment: "Once the pop up is displayed, use _Lib_PopupGetHwnd to get the handle of the pop menu. You can then pass this handle to any of the functions in A3LMenu.au3 (like reading the text, opening sub menus, etc.). If you look at the code for _Menu_ClickPopUp, you'll see this is what it does. "

Comment: I don't really have any knowledge regarding this I actually started using AutoIT just yesterday hence a sample code would be really useful, in case you can just give me a sample script that simulates the same functionality it would be great :)