# List all the options in context menu

Tags: windows, python-2.7, ui-automation, autoit, pywinauto

I want to automate the following steps using pywinauto

1) Open Windows Explorer
2) Right click on a file
3) List all the items/options that are there in the context menu that pops up when we right click a file.

Is it possible in pywinauto?

If not can it be done in AutoIt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to right click on a file present in a directory using AutoIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129714/how-to-right-click-on-a-file-present-in-a-directory-using-autoit)

Comment: @Samoth The main part that I am looking up for is listing the items in the context menu which has not been answered in the question you have mentioned

Comment: true... there is some advice in the other answer and in the comments... anyways, you may provide some example code what you have tried so far and what failed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on this forum. Check the last code which has the code which lists item in context menu.
http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/160519-click-on-item-of-a-standard-context-menu/

Answer (score 0):

I also found a way to get it using pywinauto.

i used accessibility insights tool to get the "name" property of the context menu pane as a whole.
in my case it was "Context Menu". this becomes the "title" to be put in below code:

```
#below code is the context of variable "dlg" 
app = Application(backend = "uia").start("Your_app_path.exe") 
dlg = app.Dialog
    
dlg.child_window(title="Context Menu").print_control_identifiers()
```